# scala compare elements in two sequences considering two arguments in element

Tags: scala

is there any way to get distinct elements by comparing below two sequences only considering 2nd and 3rd arguments of Person element

```
case class Person(i:Long,name:String,uname2:String,uname:String)
val firstSeq = Seq(Person(null,"aaa","bbb",null),Person(null,"bbb","ccc",null))
val secondSeq = Seq(Person(123456,"aaa","bbb","Bob"),Person(2345678,"ccc","bbb","John"),
                 Person(34567890,"bbb","ccc","Mike"))
```

Excepting result from firstSeq perceptive after comparsion `Seq(Person(null,"bbb","ccc",null))`

Excepting result from secondSeq perceptive after comparsion `Seq(Person(2345678,"ccc","bbb","John"))`

Comment: What are you looking for in the comparisons? The person with the most interesting name?

Comment: Need to get distinct elements by comparing only 2nd and 3 argument of Person element in sequences

Comment: What makes `"bbb","ccc"` more "distinct" than `"aaa","bbb"`? They look equally distinct to me.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not that clear, but this code removes elements from two lists where they share the same values of `name` and `uname2`, or where there is no corresponding value in the other list.

```
val (r1, r2) = firstSeq.zip(secondSeq).filterNot {
  case (a, b) => a.name == b.name && a.uname2 == b.uname2
}.unzip
```

Also note that it is much safer to use `Option[Int]` and `Option[String]` rather using `null` to indicate missing values.